# Is it possible to write Queries in Mongo Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

In mongo compass we have a option to write complex queries in the UI using the options button. [project,sort,collation]

[image: Mongo Compass]

In Mongo atlas we only have filter field in the UI. Is it not possible to run queries like sort in atlas itself?
(without using the  aggregations tab in UI)

[image]

If is is possible, what is the available syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such way on `MongoDB Atlas`.

But, you can connect your `MongoDB Atlas` with `MongoDB Compass` or, `Robo 3T` and perform your desired queries.

You can [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xfVX2w3TxY) which shows **How to connect MongoDB Atlas with MongoDB Compass.**